# Redirect domain.nl/pages to domain.com/nl/pages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I stopped using domain.com as DocumentRoot for domain.nl as the [WPML](https://wpml.org/) setup (WordPress Multilingual) with two domains each loading a single language from one DocumentRoot / CMS could not be done by Dreamhost admins and is no longer really condoned by [Dreamhost on managed VPS](https://www.dreamhost.com/hosting/vps/) as it requires customization of httpd.conf or working with custom vhosts. This they no longer allow on managed VPS and I understand.

I now work with one domain with the other language (nl) in a subdirectory of the .com domain. All still managed from one WP CMS using WPML

So I now I added a .htaccess to domain.nl with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.nl$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://domain.com/nl/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I added this to stop customers from seeing 404s for pages like https://domain.nl/category/very-long-post-name/ where they should see https://domain.com/nl/category/very-long-post-name/

I do not see it redirecting yet. It still 404s at https://www.domain.nl/category/very-long-post-name/

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for all those who bump into similar issues working with [mirroring](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Mirror_Domain) of domains or using ServerAliasing and or changing of the DocumentRoot ([web directory in Dreamhost](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Domains_Control_Panel#Web_directory)) to use WordPress with WPML and two domains loading two languages.

Do not forget to do these changes or or undo them for HTTPS as well. Not only for HTTP. In the Dreamhost panel there are two locations under domains > manage domains. One for HTTP and one for HTTPS. Single last column is for HTTPS
[image: secure hosting DH]
For other hosters the places are probably different or you have to do it manually